Laravel Voyager Admin Panel Can Not See Accessor
I have Product and Category model. Category entities takes parent_id which is linked to Category itself. I want to see full category tree on the admin panel. I'm trying to define an accessor named as "full_path" to the Category model. So I will use this in the Product model with category field. Here is code:
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class Category extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['name', 'description'];
    public $additional_attributes = ['full_path'];

    public function withTranslation() {
        return $this->load('translations');
    }

    public function getFullPathReadAttribute()
    {
        $path = $this->name;
        $parent = $this->parent;

        while ($parent) {
            $path = $parent->name . ' > ' . $path;
            $parent = $parent->parent;
        }

        return $path;
    }
}

But I can not see the full_path attribute when I'm creating a bread for Product.category:

What am I missing?
